# Ignore comment ranges in java file

Tags: regex, shell, grep

My target: Ignore all comments when grep in java file

Say I have file Java "test.java"

```
/*
 * multiple
 * line
 * comment
 * range
 */

line 1;
line 2;             // cmt line 2 日本語 abcd
line 3;             // cmt line 3
// cmt line 4
```

My output file should be like this:

```
line 1;
line 2;             
line 3;
```

I have to work on multiple-line regex, so I cant use normal grep.

Actually, I have tried 2 methods:

1. pcre2grep -v

```
    REGEX_IS_COMMENT ='(logger\\..*$)|([/][/].*$)|((\\/\\*)(.|[\r\n])+?(\\*\\/))'
    pcre2grep -MnvH "$REGEX_IS_COMMENT" $input> $output
```

=> Bug: -v filter "lines" that do not match regex, so all "line 2" and "line 3" would not appear in output file

2. awk and delete matched patterns

```
REGEX_IS_COMMENT ='(logger\\..*$)|([/][/].*$)|((\\/\\*)(.|[\r\n])+?(\\*\\/))'
awk 'BEGIN{RS=SUBSEP;} {print gensub(REGEX_IS_COMMENT,"", "g", $0)}' REGEX_IS_COMMENT=$REGEX_IS_COMMENT $input> $output
```

=> Bug: The dot (.) do not match Japanese characters. My output file was:

```
     line 1;
     line 2;                日本語 abcd
     line 3;
```

---

Please share some of your solutions. Thank you !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: Removing comments from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8626866/java-removing-comments-from-string)

Comment: "The dot (.) do not match Japanese characters" Isn't it because it is unicode and you should use (..)?

Comment: @IldarAkhmetov Nah, my problem contains his

Comment: @Crick3t I don't understand. I think (.) matches any character (exept for new line).  Actually pcre2grep works well with it, but somehow awk doesn't