# Remove comments from a java file and maintain file structure

Tags: java, regex

I am working on a project that requires me to remove comments from a java file. Currently, I am using the regular expression

```
(?:/\\*(?:[^*]|(?:\\*+[^*/]))*\\*+/)|(?://.*)
```

which I got from http://ostermiller.org/findcomment.html.

The regular expression works well, but the problem is that I need to preserve the file structure when I remove the comments. In other words, if I have a 3 line block comment, I need it to be replaced with 3 blank lines. This is necessary so that the code remains on the same line numbers as the original.

How would I replace the 3 line block comment with 3 blank lines?

Edit:
I was able to solve my problem by making use of SableCC.

Comment: Why do you need to remove comments? Maybe you should code your own algorithm. I don't think that this is possible using regular expressions.

Comment: I'll probably write a Perl script for that. In Java it would be a bit difficult.

Comment: Which IDE are you using? Some support this kind of thing directly.

Comment: If you're not tied to Java, you could use `sed` or `awk`. They can delete the comment while preserving the line count

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613432/remove-source-file-comments-using-intellij

Comment: how to handle multiple line comments as used in [DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/kR1eR4/6)

Comment: It makes sense to remove the comments, but remembered it's probably commented because there's an issue with the code. You might want to remove the comments only as you go through and modernize the code.

Comment: The application is used to detect plagiarism among projects submitted at university. The comments are removed so that they will not be confused with syntax. The file lines need to be preserved so that they can be used for highlighting where code has been copied. I'd prefer not to remove the comments from the original file

Answer (score 0):

I haven't fully sussed out what that regex is doing, but if it matches the entire comment, then you can get the matched comment, check to see how many newlines it contains, and then replace the match with that many newlines instead of replacing it with the empty string.

Answer (score 0):

If you're set on regex you can try this

```
~/(?:/.*?$|\*[^*]*\*/)~
```

**[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/kR1eR4/9)**

This makes use of two different non-capture groups

Since all comments (single-line and multi-line) have to start with a `/` that's the first character of the regex. Then a comment can have another `/` or a `*`. This is where the alternation comes in. The first part `/.*?$` handles single line comments, while the second part `\*[^*]*\*` matches on multi-line comments.

If your multi-line comments are formatted with leading `*` followed by a `<space>`, like this:

```
/* mu
* lti
* line
* comment
*/
```

then this **[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/hO5rO8/5)** should do the trick (I don't think a line can start with a `*` in Java, unless it's in a comment).

Unfortunately, I have not found a suitable substitution to preserve line spacing if they are not formatted as above.