# Is it possible to delete all comments in my code, in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I've been working on a project in the Android Studio, and it has a lot of comments in it. Is it possible to delete all the comments (both single line `//` and multi-line `/*`) in the code? Preferably, without dealing with regular expressions.

Comment: A regex find-all replace will probably work.

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26334680/4569506

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you do not want comments in the code that you export, IntelliJ shouldn't export your comments.
However, if you want to actually delete comments in a whole project, you can delete the `/* x */` comments by using REGEX. For the `//` comments, you may also be able to use REGEX, but watch out not to delete your whole code while doing so.

For `/* x */`

```
\/\*([\s\S]*?\*\/)
```

For `//`

```
\/\/.*
```

Comment: How do I ignore javadocs?

Comment: when we using this method even inside of "..." also removing..so it is not perfect way  for whole project