# Copy without comments in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

Is it possible (or is there a plugin) in IntelliJ IDEA that allows you to copy code without the comments contained?

Comment: I believe you could do a search/replace with a `regex` expression to eliminate them.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613432/remove-source-file-comments-using-intellij