# How to strip blank and comment lines from text file during maven compile process?

Tags: maven, comments, strip, text-files

I have a set of text files I merge into a big text file with the `maven-antrun-plugin`.

Yet, I would like to strip empty line and comment lines.

For example:

```
# Comment 1
ddd=3;

# More comment
eee=4;
fff=5;
```

would become:

```
ddd=3;
eee=4;
fff=5;
```

Is there a maven plugin for this? Or any other solution?

Comment: Quick question, why? The java compiler will ignore commented lines and meaningless whitespace. Resultant binaries will look the same with or without these changes.

Comment: It is not source code, it is resource data.

Comment: Completely mis-understood. I've updated my answer below

Answer (score 0):

It is nearly impossible to answer penultimate question in here. There are maven plugins all over the place, and new ones appear all the time.

However, I can tell you that none of the standard plugins from the Apache Maven project or the Codehaus Mojo project do this.

You could script sed from ant, or look around harder at the ant filtering capability; it might be able to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I misunderstood. You are attempting to clean-up a data file, not source code.

Since you're already using the ANT plugin, why not use the [regexp](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replaceregexp.html) task to strip your files?

```
<!-- Empty lines -->
<replaceregexp file="${datafile}"
    match="^\s*\n"
    replace=""
    byline="true" />

<!-- Comment lines -->
<replaceregexp file="${datafile}"
    match="^#.*\n"
    replace=""
    byline="true" />
```

<strike>This kind of functionality is often provided by [code obfuscation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscated_code) tools.</strike>

Never used it, but perhaps you should checkout [Proguard](http://pyx4me.com/pyx4me-maven-plugins/proguard-maven-plugin/). Another possibility is to decompile the compiled byte-code.

See these other answers:

- [Remove source file comments using IntelliJ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613432/remove-source-file-comments-using-intellij)
- [Script to remove comments in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834584/script-to-remove-comments-in-java)

Comment: Scratch that. Proguard appears to obfuscate the binaries, not the source code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my work solutions:

```xml
<!-- Remove blank lines -->

<replaceregexp
    file="<OUTPUT_FILE>"
    match="^\s*\n"
    replace=""
    flags="gm"
    byline="false"
/>

<!-- Remove comments -->

<replaceregexp
    file="<OUTPUT_FILE>"
    match="^\s*#.*\n"
    replace=""
    flags="gm"
    byline="false"
/>
```